# Django Rest Framework for network device configuration

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a network device (switch) with a REST API. 
Now, I want to create a Django application that can access this API and configures the device. Does it make sense to use the Django Rest Framework for this application?

Answer (score 1):

**Django Rest Framework** is a very good framework for REST API development, but I realize that what you want is to use an already available API. For that you only need a library to send requests to the end-points of the api.

There are several libraries for that, like [pyhton-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

This is an example of its use:

```
post_data = {'field': 'some value'}
response = requests.post('http://apidomain.com/end_point', data=post_data)
content = response.content
```